# Web scraping and saving in csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using Selenium and the automation part is working efficiently but the data is being saved in the csv inaccurately. Even though I have four addresses in my f (csv file), it only returns the data from the first address listed redundantly. It brings back the data for the first address over and over again in the csv file. How can I tell Python to just have one heading for all the columns, not Permit, Address, Street Name, etc... every time it iterates the process. Please let me know if you anyone needs further details.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
chrome = driver.get('https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx')


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

with open('C:/Users/list.csv','r') as f:
addresses = f.readlines()

for address in addresses:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').clear()       
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').send_keys(address)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_btnSearch').click()

    table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_cplMain_rgSearchRslts_ctl00")))

    df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute("outerHTML"))[0]

    with open('thematchingresults.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f)
```

The four addresses I am trying to parse for:

```
6525 Mountain Sky Rd
6543 Mountain Sky Rd
6561 Mountain Sky Rd
6579 Mountain Sky Rd
```

How the data is being fed into csv file:

```
Permit Number   Address                  Street Name     Applicant Name     Contractor Name SITE_SUBDIVISION    RECORDID
0   B13-2169    6525 MOUNTAIN SKY RD    MOUNTAIN SKY RD SHADDOCK HOMES LTD  SHADDOCK HOMES LTD  PCR - SHERIDAN  MAC:1306181017281473
1   L13-3451    6525 MOUNTAIN SKY RD    MOUNTAIN SKY RD TDS IRRIGATION  TDS IRRIGATION  SHERIDAN    ECON:131115094522681
2   ROW13-6260  6525 Mountain Sky Rd    Mountain Sky Rd AT&T Broadband & Internet Serv  Housley Group       SSW:1312030140165722
Permit Number   Address                   Street Name       Applicant Name   Contractor Name    SITE_SUBDIVISION    RECORDID
0   B13-2169    6525 MOUNTAIN SKY RD    MOUNTAIN SKY RD SHADDOCK HOMES LTD  SHADDOCK HOMES LTD  PCR - SHERIDAN  MAC:1306181017281473
1   L13-3451    6525 MOUNTAIN SKY RD    MOUNTAIN SKY RD TDS IRRIGATION  TDS IRRIGATION  SHERIDAN    ECON:131115094522681
2   ROW13-6260  6525 Mountain Sky Rd    Mountain Sky Rd AT&T Broadband & Internet Serv  Housley Group       SSW:1312030140165722
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost working perfectly, but your `wait.until()` appears to be being satisfied immediately before the page has had a chance to update itself. Simply adding a one second delay before the `wait.until()` for example worked, although you need to investigate a more rigorous approach:

```
time.sleep(2)
```

This gave me the following CSV output file:

```
,Permit Number,Address,Street Name,Applicant Name,Contractor Name,SITE_SUBDIVISION,RECORDID
0,B13-2169,6525 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,SHADDOCK HOMES LTD,SHADDOCK HOMES LTD,PCR - SHERIDAN,MAC:1306181017281473
1,L13-3451,6525 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,TDS IRRIGATION,TDS IRRIGATION,SHERIDAN,ECON:131115094522681
2,ROW13-6260,6525 Mountain Sky Rd,Mountain Sky Rd,AT&T Broadband & Internet Serv,Housley Group,,SSW:1312030140165722
,Permit Number,Address,Street Name,Applicant Name,Contractor Name,SITE_SUBDIVISION,RECORDID
0,B14-0771,6543 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,DREES CUSTOM HOMES,DREES CUSTOM HOMES,PCR - SHERIDAN,LWE:1403121043033654
1,L14-2401,6543 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,DFW SITE DESIGN,DFW SITE DESIGN,SHERIDAN,ECON:140711080345627
2,ROW15-4097,6543 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,HOUSLEY GROUP,HOUSLEY GROUP,,TLW:1507220204411002
,Permit Number,Address,Street Name,Applicant Name,Contractor Name,SITE_SUBDIVISION,RECORDID
0,B13-2364,6561 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,DREES CUSTOM HOMES,DREES CUSTOM HOMES,PCR - SHERIDAN,MAC:1307030929232194
1,L14-1500,6561 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,DFW SITE DESIGN,DFW SITE DESIGN,SHERIDAN,ECON:140424040055127
2,P15-0073,6561 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,RIVERBEND/SANDLER POOLS,,SHERIDAN,HC:1502160438345148
,Permit Number,Address,Street Name,Applicant Name,Contractor Name,SITE_SUBDIVISION,RECORDID
0,B13-2809,6579 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,SHADDOCK HOMES LTD,SHADDOCK HOMES LTD,PCR - SHERIDAN,MAC:1308050328358768
1,B13-4096,6579 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MIRAGE CUSTOM POOLS,MIRAGE CUSTOM POOLS,PCR - SHERIDAN,MAC:1312030307087756
2,L14-1640,6579 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,TDS IRRIGATION,TDS IRRIGATION,SHERIDAN,ECON:140506012624706
3,P14-0018,6579 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MIRAGE CUSTOM POOLS,,SHERIDAN,LCR:1401130949212891
4,ROW14-3205,6579 MOUNTAIN SKY RD,MOUNTAIN SKY RD,Housley Group,Housley Group,,TLW:1406190424422330
```

---

As an alternative approach, you could keep polling the table until you see new data has been loaded:

```
import pandas as pd
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Python27\chromedriver.exe")
chrome = driver.get('https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

with open('C:/Users/list.csv','r') as f:
    addresses = f.readlines()

old_table_html = []

for address in addresses:
    print address
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').clear()       
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').send_keys(address)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_btnSearch').click()

    while True:
        try:
            table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_cplMain_rgSearchRslts_ctl00")))
            table_html = table.get_attribute("outerHTML")

            if table_html != old_table_html:
                break
        except selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass

    old_table_html = table_html
    df = pd.read_html(table_html)[0]

    with open('thematchingresults.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f)
```